# Copy data through SSIS package from one machine to another

Tags: ssis

I have data in few excel sheets which are to be loaded into tables. I've created a few SSIS packages to do this on my local machine.

Now I have to move these tables onto my client's machine, which is in another location. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much data you are loading into SQL Server from Excel, you can choose different routes :

1. When designing SSIS package, you can use configuration file. The advantage is that your packages will be customizable, like when you are developing it can point to your local server and when you want to promote it to prod, you just have to change connection string to point to PROD server. Good example can be found [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1405/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-package-configuration/).
2. Use Bulk Insert to load data.
3. As @listik mentioned, you can use Import/Export wizard as well.
4. You can use linked server too as described here.

SSIS will be more flexible and customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a fairly new SQLServer, there are a couple of ways you could do this:

- Direct connection (the machines are able to "see" each other through the network, and you can open a database connection between them)
- Export file

In either scenario, you would use the SQLServer wizard to export/import, be it directly between the two databases/tables on the first case, or from a file on the second one.